Problems with Add Smart o Classic Quote to XTRF using XTRF API
I am trying to create a new Smart Quote v2 using the XTRF API with the endpoint: post /v2/quotes for example sending these parameters:
{
"name": "Test Name",
"clientId": 624,
"serviceId": 17
} 

whatever Service ID I try to send I get this problem:
{
"status": 400,
"errorMessage": "Service with id 17 is not a valid smart project or quote service.",
"detailedMessage": null
} 

so I can't create a Quote indicating the type of service. I also don't know what other data I have to add to a Quote (source language, target languages...etc) so they can correctly review and process the Quote. Is there any documentation?? or if you can give me some instructions. I can't create classic Quotes either, there is simply no endpoint for their creation.
